# ToolTip while dragging the object

Tags: wpf, tooltip, drag

I'm new `WPF`, implementing drag and drop application using `MVVM` pattern. While dragging, I want to show tooltip. I don't want to show on mousehover event but want to show on mouse move event.

I added code in `MouseMove()` method but it doesn't work.
is there any way to achieve this in xaml only.?

I tried by below way but it doesn't work

```
 ToolTip tt = new ToolTip();

    void MouseMove(.....)
    {
    var rec = sender as ListBox;
        var selectedItem = rec.SelectedItem as ListViewItem;
        rec.ToolTip = tt;
        tt.Content = "Sample ToolTip Text";
        tt.Placement = System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.PlacementMode.Relative;
        tt.HorizontalOffset = e.GetPosition((IInputElement)sender).X + 10;
        tt.VerticalOffset = e.GetPosition((IInputElement)sender).Y + 10;
        tt.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    }
```

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43702/Drag-and-Drop-in-WPF-Part-II  you can show any adorner while dragging as shown in link

Answer (score 1):

Check out this [link](http://www.hardcodet.net/2009/03/moving-data-grid-rows-using-drag-and-drop) (Moving WPF DataGrid Rows using Drag and Drop).

He hooks into the OnMouseLeftButtonDown to begin the drag operation. You could add setting a drop target hint visible (or some other visual indicator) and hide it in the OnMouseLeftButtonUp event when he resets the DragDrop.